# Reactnative Request failed with status code 400

Tags: react-native, api

i trying to build an finance management application, React Native as Frontend and Django as Backend,
i use axios to take data from user then send it to backend
it show error Request failed with status code 400

the user enter the data through form and send it to the backend , i have used Restful API that build with django and run the server locally

```
 import * as React from "react";
    import {View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput} from "react-native";
    import { COLORS, SIZES,FONTS} from '../styles/theme.js';
    import { FieldArray, Formik} from "formik";
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    const AddScreen =()=>{
    
        const radioopt = [{},{},{},{}];
    
        const submit = (val) => {
            if(val.type == "" || val.category == "" || val.amount == ""){
                alert("Please Enter all details");
                return;
            }
            // 'http://192.168.8.143:8000/transactions/'
            axios.post('http://192.168.8.143:8000/transactions/', {
               
                    "id": "1",
                    "type": val?.type,
                    "category": val.category,
                    "amount": val?.amount,
                    // "owner" : "",
                    "date" : Date.now(),
              })
              .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
        }
    
        return(
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor:COLORS.gray}}>
    
                <Formik
                initialValues={{type:'',category:'', amount:''}}
                onSubmit={(values)=>{submit(values)}}
                >
                    {(props)=>(
                        <View style={styles.whitecard}>
    
                            <TextInput
                            style={styles.inputstyle}
                            placeholder='type'
                            onChangeText={props.handleChange('type')}
                            value={props.values.type}
                            />
                            
                            <TextInput
                            style={styles.inputstyle}
                            placeholder='category'
                            onChangeText={props.handleChange('category')}
                            value={props.values.category}
                            />
                            <TextInput
                            style={styles.inputstyle}
                            placeholder='amount'
                            onChangeText={props.handleChange('amount')}
                            value={props.values.amount}
                            keyboardType='numeric'
                            />
        
    
                            <View style={{margin:10,padding:0, backgroundColor:COLORS.pink, borderRadius:6}}>
                            <Button title='Submit' color='white' onPress={props.handleSubmit}></Button>
    
                            </View>
    
                        </View>
                    )}
                </Formik>
    
            </View>
        );
    
    
    
    }
    
  ...
export default AddScreen;
```

i try my code with fake API and it work, please let me know if the error caused by the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Did you allow HTTP requests for android and for ios? To allow HTTP requests follow this.

For Android:
Add the following attributes to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest 
    //..... rest code
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> 
    
        // ----------------
    
    </application>
</manifest>
```

For IOS.
if you want to allow everything writes this inside info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>yourdomain.com</key>
    <dict>
        <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
 </dict>
</dict>
```

For expo IOS edit your app.json and app.json -> infoPlist -> NSAppTransportSecurity -> true

```
"ios": {
  "supportsTablet": true,
  "infoPlist": {
    "NSAppTransportSecurity" : {
      "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" : true,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i am using react-native with Expo

Comment: I edited my answer and also added an answer for expo. Even this does not work then you can use ngrok to host your local server.

Comment: still the error is shown, did you think it cause by the backend??

Comment: I think to be absolutely sure, can you try to call a dummy API like "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" and see if you get the result or not also check with an HTTP API and check that is it working or not.